# In EmberJS, How to organize templates inside a parent layout, and how to define their Routes?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to have a App that has two main models: Account and Transaction.
I want to have a list of Accounts on a left bar.
When I click on an Account, I want a list of Transactions to be listed on the center of the page.
And when I click on a Transaction, I want the details of that transaction to appear on a right bar. And last but not least, when I click Edit Transaction, I want to show a small Transaction form in this same right bar, just bellow Transaction details.

My problem is I can't get the right routes and templates names to work. Do I do a huge nested router map like this (could not get it to work)? I also would like to make use of Ember "partial" to edit this Transaction.

```
this.resource('accounts', function(){
    this.resource('account',{ path: ':account_id' }, function(){
        this.resource('transactions', function(){
            this.resource('transaction', {path:':transaction_id'});
        });
    });
});
```

If so, how do I name my templates?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="main">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="accounts">
    <div class="left-bar">
        {{#each model}}
            {{#linkTo 'transactions' this}} {{name}} {{/linkTo}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class="right-main">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="accounts/transactions">
    <div class="center">
        {{#each model}}
            {{#linkTo 'transaction' this}} {{name}} {{/linkTo}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="accounts/transactions/transaction">
    <div class="top-transaction-detail">
        Transaction description: {{description}}<br>
        Transaction value: {{value}}
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-transaction-edit">
        {{partial 'transaction/edit'}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="transaction/_edit">
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='description'}}</p>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='value'}}</p>
</script>
```

Also, what would be my Routes?

```
App.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
App.AccountsAccountTransactionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
App.AccountsAccountTransactionsTransactionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
??????
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I can't get the right routes and templates names to work. Do I do a huge nested router map like this (could not get it to work)?

Yes, you've got the right idea. Sometimes this level of nesting does not make sense but in your case it is a good fit since you actually want that level of nesting in your application ui. Only change is I would make accounts and transactions the default by setting path to '/'.

```
this.resource('accounts', {path: '/'}, function(){
  this.resource('account',{ path: ':account_id' }, function(){
    this.resource('transactions', {path: '/'}, function(){
        this.resource('transaction', {path:':transaction_id'});
    });
  });
});
```

> If so, how do I name my templates?

```
application.hbs
accounts.hbs
accounts/index.hbs -> "choose an account" message
account.hbs -> account details
transactions.hbs -> list of transactions for the account
transactions/index.hbs -> "choose a transaction" message
transaction.hbs -> transaction details
transaction/index.hbs -> an edit button
transaction/edit.hbs -> the edit form
```

At least I think that's right, it's pretty easy to mess up the naming conventions. When in doubt, try adding the following to your application config:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});
```

That way you can see what ember is using and fix anything that was named incorrectly.

> I also would like to make use of Ember "partial" to edit this Transaction.

I'd recommend using another route instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I just got a little bit confused with your hbs stuff.  transactions.hbs and transactions/index.hbs wouldn't be the same goal? I just want a list of transactions for the account, and when  I click in one of them, I open the details with transaction/index.hbs (or transaction.hbs)? Well .... I will try some of them, thanks.

Comment: Mike, can you also point out where I can know more about .hbs? Is this something to put handlebars templates in their own files? How do I use it? Tks

Comment: So re: the templates: transactions.hbs would have an {{outlet}} that at first is filled with transaction/index.hbs and that template just has a message saying to select a transaction. when one is chosen, the route changes and the outlet gets filled with transaction.hbs which shows the details of the transaction

Comment: Re: .hbs, thats the extension i tend to use when saving handlebars templates. At first I'd recommend you stick with script tags in a single file, then once your app gets large enough maybe look into build tools. There are many, if using rails you can just use ember-rails gem. If not, try ember-tools project.